# How to edit your progam icon?

Tags: python

I am a python programer, and I am new to the site. I was wondering how to add a image to to my python program (What I mean is whenever you finish making your program, you close you GUI window etc. Then you click on your program icon). I tried to right-click on the icon and went to properties, and I found nothing to change it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which GUI toolkit do you use?

Comment: usually you use some kind of `--icon my_icon.ico` switch when you build your exe

Comment: That's totally dependent on your OS/Platform/Window system/Toolkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows, you can create a shortcut to the python file that runs your program and then change the icon of the shortcut.  To create a shortcut, right-click on the .py file from explorer and select 'Create Shortcut'.  Then right-click on the shortcut and select 'Change Icon'.

Comment: Um... so i did what you said, dwxw, but it want let me use my own pictures?